# Проблема с делением. C++

Tags: c++, c

Нужно разделить две переменные `i` и `j`. Но при делении `i/j` выводится 0 (`j > i`). Как исправить?

```
int n;
cin >> n;
double otv;

for(int i = 2;i<=n-1;i++){
    for(int j = 3;j<=n;j++){
        otv += (i*1.0)/j;
    }
}

cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << otv;
```

Answer (score 7):

Для начала - а инициализировать

```
double otv;
```

должен Дейкстра? :)

И еще - я бы переписал вот так:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
double otv = 0.0;

for(int i = 2; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 3; j <= n; j++)
    {
        otv += double(i)/j;
    }
}

cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << otv;
```

Все считается и выводится нормально...

Кстати, ваш вопрос

> Но при делении i/j выводится 0 (j > i). Как исправить?

получил у вас же ответ - в виде умножения на `1.0`, т.е. на вычисление результата как деления двух чисел `double`. Так что *зачем* вы спрашиваете то, на что ответили сами - непонятно. Я обошел это иначе - приведением одного из значений к `double`.
Без этого выполняется целочисленное деление, которое при `j>i` дает нуль.

Comment: Вы поняли, какую задачу автор решает? Смотрю на эти циклы и не соображу, что же все таки ему нужно.

Comment: А ещё можно поменять циклы местами, после чего нижний цикл заменяется на 1 операцию (что-то в духе (n(n+1)-1)/j )

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Нет, какая-то сумма дробей, но... Есть подозрение, что автор где-то налажал (почему в одном случае n, в другом n-1? ну и так далее... Но - об этом вопроса не было :)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто указать какое-то значение переменной otv, например, ноль.